# Make nice animation between pages

Tags: c#, xaml, animation

I'm creationg an app for Windows store that includes few pages and in each page different background image (the image covers all the screen).
I eant that the animation between the pages will look nice.
I used `EntranceThemeTransition` and when the content first appear there is a nice animation. But when the image appear there is no animation. Can I create some animation for the background image so the navigation will be nice?

This is my XAML code in one of the pages (if it is needed)

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="assets/sunset.jpg" x:Name="cc"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Container">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"   Margin="413,138,438,0" Height="550" Width="515" x:Name="FormContainer">
                <TextBox Margin="133,249,131,269" PlaceholderText="Email" BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="Email"/>   
                <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251" Height="8" PlaceholderText="Password"  BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="Password"/>
                <Button Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,358,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" Height="50" Background="#FF235085" BorderBrush="#FF6749AC" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.9" RequestedTheme="Light" Click="Login_Click"/>

            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up the animations in the XAML.  Then you can trigger the FadeInAnimation in your code after loading the image.

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Name="LoadImageStoryboard">
    <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundImage" />
  </Storyboard>

  <Storyboard x:Name="LoadGridStoryboard">
    <FadeOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundImage" />
  </Storyboard>

</Page.Resources>
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        Loaded='Grid_Loaded'>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height='3*' />
      <RowDefinition Height='13*' />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Click='Button_Click'
            Content='Load Image'
            HorizontalAlignment='Center' />
    <Image x:Name='BackgroundImage'
           HorizontalAlignment='Center'
           Source='assets/sunset.jpg'
           Grid.RowSpan='1'
           Grid.Row='1' />
  </Grid>
```

**Code**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

  // load image here...

  LoadImageStoryboard.Begin();
}

private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  LoadGridStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: this was the answer from your previous question, the one you deleted. It might need tweeking to fit this question.

Comment: Thanks but when I debug the your fixes I just see a black color in the background.

Comment: I haven't tested this to see if it works for ImageBrush.  It should work if you refactor your code and put an image element on the page and set it so it's behind all the UI on the page.

Comment: Thanks it works great, is there any way that the fading in will be showed when the page loaded? I tried this `private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  LoadImageStoryboard.Begin();
}` But it doesn't work.